# How to change size of turtle?

Tags: python, resize, turtle-graphics

I am trying to double the size of the turtle in the window every time I press `x` on my keyboard. I tried using `.turtlesize(2,2,2)`, but that's not right. I need to double every time the key is pressed so if the turtle size is `(1,1,1)`, it will become `(2,2,2)` then `(4,4,4)` and so on each time I press `x`.

This is what I have so far:

```
import turtle
turtle.setup(500,500)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Commands")
wn.bgcolor("black")

tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.shape("triangle")
tess.color("red")
tess.left(90)

def increaseSize():
    size = tess.turtlesize()
    increase = tuple([2 * num for num in size])
    tess.turtlesize(increase) #this is where the error occurs

wn.onkey(increaseSize, "x")
wn.listen()
```

Comment: What specific error message do you get?

Answer (score 6):

The default size of a `Turtle` object is `20` pixels, which is the equivalent of the ratio `1` when resizing the `Turtle`.

For example:

```
import turtle

tess = turtle.Turtle()
print(tess.shapesize())
```

Output:

```
(1.0, 1.0, 1)
```

The first two `1.0`s in the tuple represents how many units 20 pixels the `Turtle`'s width and height are, and the last `1` represents the width of the `Turtle`'s outline.
You won't be able to see the outline if you only pass one argument into the `tess.color()` brackets, because by default, there is no outline.

To increase the `Turtle`'s size, simply pass in the number of 20 pixels you want each of the `Turtle`'s dimensions to be into [`tess.shapesize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.shapesize) or [`tess.turtesize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.turtlesize):

```
import turtle

tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.shapesize(2, 3, 1) # Sets the turtle's width to 60px and height to 90px
```

---

The other answer points out that the `turtlesize` function does not take in an
array; it takes in `int`s or `float`s, so you'll need to [unpack the tuple with a `*`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/13552470)
when you pass the tuple into the function.

In your `increaseSize` function, the `tuple` and `[]` wrappers aren't necessary,
and only wastes efficiency. Simply use `()`:

```
def increaseSize():
    size = tess.turtlesize()
    increase = (2 * num for num in size)
    tess.turtlesize(*increase)
```

On top of your code there is

```
turtle.setup(500,500)
wn = turtle.Screen()
```

Since you defined a `Screen` object, `wn`, it's cleaner to use `wn.setup()` instead of `turtle.setup()`:

```
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(500,500)
```

All together:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(500,500)

tess = turtle.Turtle("triangle")
tess.color("red")
tess.left(90)

def increaseSize():
    size = tess.turtlesize()
    increase = (2 * num for num in size)
    tess.turtlesize(*increase)

wn.onkey(increaseSize, "x")
wn.listen()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer!  Should be used a template for *how to write a good answer* !

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
tess.turtlesize(increase)
```

to instead be:

```
tess.turtlesize(*increase)
```

`turtlesize()` wants three separate values but you were passing one tuple of three values so we need to spread that tuple across the argument list.