# Is it possible to change the size of the turtle in python Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've Tried shapesize and turtlesize neither work,
is there an alternative?

everything else works I just need a rectangle shape

```
    class Sword(turtle.Turtle):

        def __init__(self,plyr,color):
            turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
            self.player = plyr
            self.speed(0)
            self.up()
            self.fd(25)
            self.goto(self.player.xcor(),self.player.ycor())
            self.shape("square")
            self.color(color)

        def collision(self):
            global zombies
            for x in range(len(zombies)-1,-1,-1):
                if self.distance(zombies[x]) <= 20:
            zombies[x].ht()
            del zombies[x]
            return True;
    s = Sword(p1,"blue")
```

Comment: So your question is **Is it possible to change the *shape* of the turtle**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change size of turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103158/how-to-change-size-of-turtle)

Answer (score 2):

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.shape('square')
t.shapesize(2.0, 1.0, 1) # width, len, outline
```

[The full documentation for the turtle module is readily available.](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the size of the turtle/shape you should try using the shapesize() function. Hope this helps!