# Make Turtle Bigger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have been trying to make a size difference but am unable to. Do I add or edit a line? Help is very much appriciated. Here is my code.

```
import turtle

#first turtle
my_turtle1 = turtle.Turtle()
my_turtle1.shape("square")
my_turtle1.screen.bgcolor("white")
my_turtle1.color('black')
my_turtle1.setheading(90)

#second turtle
my_turtle2 = turtle.Turtle()
my_turtle2.setposition(50,0)
my_turtle2.shape("square")
my_turtle2.color('black')
my_turtle2.setheading(90)

#3rd turtle
my_turtle3 = turtle.Turtle()
my_turtle3.setposition(100,0)
my_turtle3.shape("square")
my_turtle3.color('black')
my_turtle3.setheading(90)

#4th turtle
my_turtle4 = turtle.Turtle()
my_turtle4.setposition(150,0)
my_turtle4.shape("square")
my_turtle4.color('black')
my_turtle4.setheading(90)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change size of turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103158/how-to-change-size-of-turtle)

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 probably better to give a link to docs instead of a stackoverflow question on how to pass `.turtlesize()` a list

Comment: docs for `.turtlesize()` here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.turtlesize

Comment: @KetZoomer I didn't actually comment it. When you mark as duplicate, the system automatically posts a comment on your behalf saying "Does this answer your question? questionTitleHereWithLink"

Comment: oh, okay, I did not know that, thanks, but I do not think that it is a duplicate, as that question asked how to pass it a list

Comment: looking at docs would be better @scriptiv instead of a SO question

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```py
import turtle

#first turtle
my_turtle1 = turtle.Turtle()
my_turtle1.turtlesize(90, 90, 1) # pass, stretch width, stretch_len, outline, to this function like in the docs

turtle.done()
```

Link to docs: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.turtlesize

Comment: For me, it makes the turtle bigger but it doesn't change the size of the squares.

Comment: yes, it only makes the turtle bigger, and that's what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to say by making turtle bigger. Is it the size of the turtle or the shape.
For making the turtle bigger-use turtlesize()
For the shape,use shapesize()
I hope you find it helpful : )

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30255292)